# ConnectionTimeout Error When Using net-ssh With Options that Work with ssh Command?

Tags: ruby, ssh, net-ssh

I'm trying to use [the net-ssh documentation](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/Net/SSH.html) to connect to a remote server. I'm using the following options:

- `:username`
- `:port`
- `:keys`
- `:host`

with values set equal to the values of the `Host` that I have configured in my `~/.ssh/config` file that I use for connecting to the same remote server using the `ssh` command. However, I'm getting an error when trying to run the following line in `irb`:

```
session = Net::SSH.start( # my options here # )
```

Error:

```
Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout
    from /Users/jake/.gem/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:90:in `rescue in initialize'
    from /Users/jake/.gem/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:57:in `initialize'
    from /Users/jake/.gem/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:237:in `new'
    from /Users/jake/.gem/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:237:in `start'
    from (irb):14
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Is this a configuration/argument error on my part or do I need to call a different command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was that I was specifying my arguments incorrectly. If you're using options, you need to specify your `host` and `username` as position arguments and then you can use hashes for the rest of the arguments. Doing:

```
Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', :port => #my port#, :keys => ['/path/to/key'])
```

worked for me.